# SetMultiChoiceItems in android with dynamic list array

Tags: java, android

i have been trying to show some data in dynamic array after fetching it from server and the code results with this error "Cannot resolve method 'setMultiChoiceItems(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>, boolean[], anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)'"

Code for alert dialog is

ArrayList category_options = new ArrayList<>();
selectedCategories = new boolean[category_options.size()];

```
    categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Initialize alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);

            // set title
            builder.setTitle("Select Category");

            // set dialog non cancelable
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(category_options, selectedCategories , new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b) {
                    // check condition
                    if (b) {
                        // when checkbox selected
                        // Add position  in lang list
                        CatList.add(i);
                        // Sort array list
                        Collections.sort(CatList);
                    } else {
                        // when checkbox unselected
                        // Remove position from langList
                        CatList.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // Initialize string builder
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    // use for loop
                    for (int j = 0; j < CatList.size(); j++) {
                        // concat array value
                        stringBuilder.append(category_options.get(CatList.get(j)));
                        // check condition
                        if (j != CatList.size() - 1) {
                            // When j value  not equal
                            // to lang list size - 1
                            // add comma
                            stringBuilder.append(", ");
                        }
                    }
                    // set text on textView
                    categories.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // dismiss dialog
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNeutralButton("Clear All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // use for loop
                    for (int j = 0; j < selectedCategories.length; j++) {
                        // remove all selection
                        selectedCategories[j] = false;
                        // clear language list
                        CatList.clear();
                        // clear text view value
                        categories.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
            // show dialog
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Someone please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The method [setMultiChoiceItems](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D,%20boolean%5B%5D,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)) needs a CharSequence[] on the first parameter, but you are passing an ArrayList.

You should define category_options like this:

```
String[] category_options = new String[numberOfItems];
```